# Using Cryptography with Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cryptography

So I have been doing some coursework on creating an appointment booking system and I am currently looking into the employee logins. I want to be able to encrypt the passwords of employees for storage and comparisons.

My problem is that I have to get the password from their Entry box but as a result I don't know how to convert the data to bytes so that it can be encrypted. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
import tkinter as tk
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)

MEDIUM_FONT = ("Berlin Sans FB", 12)
LARGE_FONT = ("Berlin Sans FB", 16)

#validate function
def validateStylist(window):
    password = bstr(passwordEntry.get())
    cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(password)
    plain_text = cipher_suite.decrypt(cipher_text)
    print(plain_text)

window = tk.Tk()

titleLabel = tk.Label(window, text="Register Stylist", font=LARGE_FONT, bg="#FFC0CB")
titleLabel.grid(columnspan = 4)

#Password
passwordLabel = tk.Label(window, text="Password:", font=MEDIUM_FONT, bg="#FFC0CB")
passwordLabel.grid(row=1,column=3)
passwordVar = tk.StringVar(window)
passwordEntry = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=passwordVar)
passwordEntry.grid(row=2,column=3)

finishButton = tk.Button(window, text="Finish",
                          command=validateStylist(window))
finishButton.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky="ew")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I suggest breaking this down to the most basic components required to encrypt a string. We do not need all of your code. Just a simple string variable that is passed into a function set up like your encryption method. This would be functional enough to figure out where you problem may be with encrypting the string.  Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is this a better example to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encode the string to utf-8 before passing it to encrypt:

```
password = passwordEntry.get().encode("utf-8")
cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(password)
```